# Pandas and ploting graph

Tags: python, pandas, graph

Hi team Am new to pandas and graph can you please help, I have two columns in excel sheet that is car name and speed, I want to put a graph with x axis speed and in y axis average speed of 25 50 75 100 125 150.

Comment: Could you put a sample of your data and your desirable output here?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)